# How can wheel factorization be used to improve Sieve of Eratosthenes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, sieve-theory

Is there a way to improve the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) by using wheel factorization? Or would using [wheel factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization) to sieve make it really not the Sieve of Eratosthenes anymore?

For example [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) states

> Implement the   Sieve of Eratosthenes...[without optimizations]
>
> That means especially that you shouldn't optimize by using
>   pre-computed wheels, i.e. don't assume you need only to cross out odd
>   numbers (wheel based on 2), numbers equal to 1 or 5 modulo 6 (wheel
>   based on 2 and 3), or similar wheels based on low primes.
>
> If there's an easy way to add such a wheel based optimization,
>   implement it as an alternative version.

What is meant by pre-computed wheel? I can see how one can not bother considering even numbers when doing the SOE but for larger primes (even 3) it becomes non-trivial to know which integer is the next non-multiple so you  end up just doing SOE anyway.

There's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892313/sieve-of-eratosthenes-with-wheel-factorization) but I don't see how anything there could be considered SOE.

Comment: I'm not sure why you "don't see how anything there could be considered" the Sieve of Eratosthenes.  I can understand you found the size of the wheel something that needs to be accounted for "to know which integer is the next non-multiple", but in the sieve we are marking off entries that *are* multiples (of a candidate divisor).  We collect all "non-multiple" entries as not marked off at the end of the process.  If you are planning or trying to program this, I think the steps will become evident when you proceed with the $2,3$-wheel, i.e. treating only candidates congruent to $1,5 \bmod 6$.

Comment: @hardmath is the idea when combing wheel factorization with SOE, that a wheel (of arbitrary size) is used to eliminate some composites, then SOE can be applied to the remaining to remove the remaining composites?

Comment: Yes, that's how I interpret the wording of the exercise -- first you do a "pure" Sieve of Eratosthenes implementation, and after that's done, if "there's an easy way," incorporate an optimization of "wheels".  The challenge is mainly how to adapt the "stride" of striking out multiples of a prime larger than those defining the "wheel".

Comment: @hardmath you know you're writing is really hard to follow. First you say "Yes, that's how I interpret the wording of the exercise" but then you describe the exact opposite: doing the SOE first and then wheel factorization. I can't understand how it makes sense doing it in that order. Even in wheel then sieve order, I don't see how it's an optimization as all that will happen is some composites will be crossed off earlier but will be crossed off again. i.e. sieve wouldn't somehow know "all multiples of this prime have been crossed off so skip it"

Comment: The exercise (as you quoted) says "Implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes...[without optimizations]".  So that's the first step of writing code.  Get that working correctly.  The introduction of wheel factorization is later in the sense of revising your code.  I'm not talking about the ordering of steps in your final code, but the order of revisions of your code.